# Poll files from read-only filesystem repeatedly (idempotent=false) with Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, producer-consumer, idempotent

I am using polling consumer pattern to read all files from given read-only directory and process them. Is there a option to ignore idempotency ?

I understand that route defined with noop=true & idempotent=false would crash whole system (infinite loop) but pooling consumer pattern is one-time operation which is triggered at given moment.

Comment: do you have a reference to 'Pooling Consumer Pattern', the one I know is the 'Polling Consumer Pattern' which is implemented by the file2 endpoint. What is the use-case that the same files should be repeatedly sent down the pipeline?

Comment: I am scanning (indexing) all files in given directory. This operation should not modify files or directories in any way and It should be repeatable. As I am indexing folder for second time default idempotency settings causes that no files are readed (as Camel caches all previously readed files into repository cache...)

Comment: you can always use a database IdempotentCache and clear the table before the next run. Still it is a very weird use-case, reminds me of some requests I got from clueless business users.

Comment: What kind of event triggers the files read?

Answer (score 4):

The camel file2 endpoint would not crash the system, since it polls 2x per second by default. It would create a message from all files which are in that folder at the time. (well, there are some options to ignore recently modified files, but most of them). e.g. the files are sent 2x per second down the pipeline.

Idempotency is off by default, unless 'noop' is passed to essentially leave the files in the input folder. However each time the endpoint polls, all files would go through the pipe. I normally move the files after processing (or before with preMove if I have multiple consumers) to avoid these duplicates and still avoid the complexity of idempotency storage.

There is no way to disable the  idempotent flag when noop is chosen :

```
    FileConsumer result = newFileConsumer(processor, operations);

    if (isDelete() && getMove() != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot set both delete=true and move options");
    }

    // if noop=true then idempotent should also be configured
    if (isNoop() && !isIdempotentSet()) {
        log.info("Endpoint is configured with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well");
        setIdempotent(true);
    }
```

the idempotent flag is reset in that case after the consumer is created.

What can be done is to create a trivial implementation of an IdempotentRepository (http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/IdempotentRepository.html) which ignores all updates and tells the endpoint it has never seen this file before.

```
    package com.company;

    import org.apache.camel.spi.IdempotentRepository;

    public class DummyIdempotentRepository implements IdempotentRepository {
        @Override
        public boolean add(Object key) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object key) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean remove(Object key) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean confirm(Object key) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void start() throws Exception {

        }

        @Override
        public void stop() throws Exception {

        }
    }
```

Something like this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read files on a specific event use `pollEnrich` with the file consumer:

```
from("direct:readFile")
    .setHeader("CamelFileName", simple("${body}"))
    .pollEnrich("file:///base/folder?fileName=${body}&noop=true", 500)
    .process(...)
```

Comment: would this not have the same issue with the IdempotentRepository storing the processed files so they are not processed again next time? For one reason or another that is a requirement of the OP.

Comment: I don't understand @martin-v problem: I don't know whether he wants to prevent re-reading a file without renaming the file (custom idempotentrepository like yours is a solution) or he wants to read the files less frequently when they are updated and a event triggered (my solution).