# Apache Camel ftp: with idempotent repository, repository value not removed

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, apache-camel, idempotent

I have a Spring Boot 2.5 application using Apache Camel 3 ftp component.

The route reads from the ftp server and writes the file to the local file system.

Multiple application instances will be running so file locking is required. I am using a Redis idempotent repository (RedisIdempotentRepository).

I am testing the robustness of the lock with 400 files.

The route is below with the key arguments.

```
from("ftp://" + ftpHost +
                "/" + ftpRootDirectory +
                "&localWorkDirectory=" + declarationRootDirectory +
                "&delay=5s" +
                "&readLock=idempotent" +
                "&recursive=true&binary=true&delete=true" +
                "&idempotent=true&shuffle=true" +
                "&readLockRemoveOnCommit=true" +
                "&idempotentRepository=#ftdFtpIdempotentRepository"
.to("file://" + declarationRootDirectory);
```

With the above the file name is added to the repository but it is not deleted once the file has been processed. The following parameter does not seem to work.
'readLockRemoveOnCommit=true'

If the key is not removed then another file with the same name on the ftp server will not be processed. I don't really want to leave it up to an eviction policy. I assume the ftp component should be removing the entry from the repository.

Can someone indicate why the repo entry is not being removed?

Looking at the source code it seems only an InProgressRepository will remove the repo entry. This is not stated in the Camel documentation.

I have tried it and it works. But after a few testing iterations the route eventually fails to process the files. I'm not sure if this is a bug but failing to process the files isn't acceptable.

Using a combination of both  'idempotentRepository' and 'inProgressRepository' also works. I notice that the ftp component will attempt to add repo entry twice. But overall it does what i need and it seems robust.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html#_default_when_consuming_files) camel-ftp doesn't delete consumed files by default. Due to this removing the entry from `idempotentRepository` would cause ftp consumer endpoint to process the file over and over again which is exactly what idempotentRepository is trying to prevent by keeping the entry.

**Ways around this:**

1. Use different file names by adding something like timestamp or guid to the file.
2. Don't use idempotentRepository and instead delete or move the files to hidden .done directory with options `delete=true` or `move=.done`

   - If you prefer to move processed files elsewhere like separate processed folder you can use something like `move=/somepath/processed/${file:name}`
   - Since you're using `recursive=true` be sure to place it outside the folder that ftp component polls for new files.
3. Create and use [DummyIdempotentRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353440/16480631) that allows reading same file multiple times no matter what.

   - Probably causes problems with your `readLock=idempotent` setting.