# Taking input from multiple files to a camel route

Tags: file, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I want to write a camel route which will take input from multiple file destination and process them after aggregating.
is it possible to take input from multiple files for a single route?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [poll-enrich](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html) to call consumer-endpoints like file to enrich the message. This works for many other consumer-endpoints as well like SFTP or message queues.

If you need to read same file multiple times it can get trickier as you'll likely have to set noop=true and possibly use something like [dummy idempotent repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352792/poll-files-from-read-only-filesystem-repeatedly-idempotent-false-with-apache-c/30353440#30353440) to get around camels default behavior.

Note that calling pollEnrich seems to clear headers / create new message so use exchange properties to persist data between pollEnrich calls.

```java
from("file:someDirectory")
    .setProperty("file1").body()
    .pollEnrich("file:otherDirectory", 3000)
    .setProperty("file2").body()
    .pollEnrich("file:yetAnotherDirectory", 3000)
    .setProperty("file3").body();
```