# Apache Camel PollEnrich cacheSize(-1)

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using a route to perform this:

When a file is sent to sftpEndpoint, I use pollEnrich to check if I received and Ack for this file.

If the ack file containt an error code, I throw an exception and the route is performed again to redeliver the file.

And when I try to check the ack another time in the first redelivery, the ack file isn't consumed beacause it has the same name as the ack generated in the first time (the ack name must not be changed after the redelivery).

```
from(sendFileToSftpEndpoint)
    .errorHandler(noErrorHandler()).to(sftpEndpoint)
        .pollEnrich().simple(sftpAckEndpoint)
        .aggregationStrategy(new RequestAcknowledgementAggregator())
        .process(new AcknowledgmentReceivingChecker())
```

According to the documentation, I have to use cacheSize(-1).

```
from(sendFileToSftpEndpoint)
    .errorHandler(noErrorHandler()).to(sftpEndpoint)
        .pollEnrich().simple(sftpAckEndpoint).cacheSize(-1)
        .aggregationStrategy(new RequestAcknowledgementAggregator())
        .process(new AcknowledgmentReceivingChecker())
```

But using cacheSize(-1) resolve the problem only for the first redelivery as the ack file is consumed again, but in the next redelivery (2nd 3rd ...) it's not consumed again.

Comment: Since you're using variables with your SFTP uris it's difficult to know what query parameters you're using. Are you using `noop=true` and want to consume file with same name twice? If so have you looked in to creating and using custom [IdempotentRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352792/poll-files-from-read-only-filesystem-repeatedly-idempotent-false-with-apache-c/30353440#30353440) 
 with your sftp consumer endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Yes I'm using noop = true and I changed it to noop = false but I had the same result.

Comment: `noop = true` prevents camel from moving or deleting the processed files after succesful exchange.  If noop is enabled camel will automatically set `idempotent = true` which enables `MemoryIdempotentRepository` that prevents files from getting consumed twice. To get Around this you can use DummyIdempotentRepository which I linked previously. You'll need to add it to your registry and then add `idempotentRepository=#nameInRegistry` to your sftp uri

Comment: Thanks but even when I put noop = false, I still face the same problem

Comment: Which is why you should probably use noop = true with the custom IdempotentRepository